# is there a way to join list of strings in sublist

Tags: python, list, join, sublist

I have the following sublist:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g']]
```

But is it possible to join the list in the sublist?

```
[['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef'], ['g']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> L = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g']]
>>> [[''.join(x)] for x in L]
[['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef'], ['g']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can use map for it

```
>>> L = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g']]
>>> map(lambda x: [''.join(x)], L)
[['ab'], ['cd'], ['ef'], ['g']]
```